# sed Error with Cordova for Ubuntu Touch

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, compiling, sed

i've run into an sed error while trying to build an app for ubuntu touch.

http://pastebin.com/uj1VnhFu

For some weird reason cordova still uses 14.10 framework as default. Since 14.10 isn't supported anymore, i had to use this command:
cordova -d build ubuntu --device -- --framework ubuntu-sdk-15.04

Due to the lack of proper documentation this command was hard to find. -.-

I have the most recent versions installed. I also wrote to the mailing list a week ago, but i didn't get an answer yet. Would be nice, if someone could help. I need especially the sqlite functionality of cordova. That's why i chose it.

Comment: *"Keine Eingabedateien"* = *"No input files"* so it's not really a sed error, it's telling you that the `find` command doesn't find anything I think

Comment: Thanks. Apparently a bug in the platform files. I've postet an answer with description, i've got from the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had contact with one of the developers. Apparently that's a bug in the current version of cordova-ubuntu. It will be fixed in the next version. Until then there is a work around. It's described there:

https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg17519.html